# gui for mpi program

Tags: c++, user-interface, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I have a problem about a simple mpi program.This program have some 3D points and these points are moving during the program. I created an simple code by implemented c++ and then I tried to add an simple gui. I used gnuplot library and I have a problem. When I call the gui function the gui is created and it is disappeared at the same time. I mean, point object have x,y,z coordinate and I have an array that includes point objects. I want to create them as gui. Can you help me about this problem?

Thanks for any help..

Comment: You need to be more precise about what you're doing. Maybe even put some snippets of code up.

Answer (score 1):

what about [Qt](http://www.trolltech.com/4.5/)? You could use the [Qt Graphics View Framework](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/graphicsview.html) to simulate the 3D-environment - it even supports coordinate transformation (ok, it was originally designed for 2d scope). It supports OpenGL and maybe you are able to simulate the 3D points by drawing dots and setting their positions using simple cosinus and tangens mathematics.

Don't get afraid of the many functions and classes Qt offers - it's very easy and fast to learn - just check out the simple [tutorials](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/tutorials.html) and after that you right can start your gui!

...and if you are used to Qt, you'll never want to miss it :)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the plot is up correctly but that then your program ends? Ie everything's correct, the window goes up, but the next thing that happens is that the program is done, and the window gets destroyed? Try putting in a couple lines that wait for a keypress right after you throw up the window. Then, the window will stay until you press a key (and **then** the program will end).